# WebServices reference issue

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to implement webservices in my porject but the reference can't be found. What might be the issue here? What am I missing?
This is how I reference the Web service. I went to the project root in the solution explorer. Right click and Add Web Reference. It showed the method and everything but when I go in the code to make reference I can't find it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using net.webservicex.www;
```

Comment: What namespace did you tell it to use? Is the net.webservicex.www accurate?

Comment: where do I do that? Actually that's the name of the website where I am pulling from the method that I call in my code. I don't think that I need to create a proxy service since I am just consuming an existing webservice from the web?

Comment: I found the problem. You need to create a new website in order to show all the elements from the webservice.

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a new *anything*...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. You need to create a new website in order to show all the elements from the webservice. Creating a new Project was not giving me the expected results to be able to connect to the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by the comments under the question...

If you are using a web-reference (2.0), you are asked for a "web reference name"; this doubles as your namespace to the item. You can access the service via something like `MyWebReferenceName.MyServiceName`.

When you use the "add service reference" dialog (3.0+), you are prompted for a "namespace", which acts identically. In this case, the service is available at something like `MyWebServiceReferenceName.MyServiceNameClient`.